# @Ajax.ActionLink - passing value of text-area to controller, and a data-something attribute

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the story:

I am making a commenting system, and when a user wants to add a comment they need to put data in a text area. I want to take that value typed by the user and make an @Ajax link which is to send that as a parameter to a controller.

I am using ASP.NET MVC5, and in my View() I have the following:

```
<textarea class="textArea" rows="3"></textarea>
        <br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Send",
                         "AddComment",
                         new { parametar = 0 , Contents = GetText() },
                         new AjaxOptions
                         {
                            UpdateTargetId = "beforeThis",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
                            HttpMethod = "GET"
                         },
                         new { @class = "postavi btn btn-primary" })
```

I tried inserting under this the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetText() {
        return "hello there!";
    }
</script>
```

I have in error saying that:

**the name GetText does not exists in the current Context**
(this is in the parameters of the @Ajax.ActionLink)

It seems I cannot integrate javascript (which could fetch me this value and razor code) How do I work this out???
PS> I have searched around for this, and either the answers for much earlier versions of MVC or the answers did not worked when I tried the same.

Comment: Your action link is a GET and your should never use a GET for modifying data - it needs to be a POST, - not to mention which if the entered text is large you would exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. Use a form and submit the value to a POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you import this namespace:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
```

Comment: Where to import this? And how may i ask? ( just using)

Comment: try to add this in the controller @EdwardSnowden

Comment: Did, no change.

Answer (score 0):

You might add an event handler to the ajax link to update a custom route value.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "Send", new {id = "xxx"}, new AjaxOptions(){}, new { onclick = "addParameter(this)" })

function addParameter(e) {
        e.href = e.href.replace("xxx", "HelloWord");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is that you want the razor to call your JavaScript code and this is impossible. This is because Views will be rendered to HTML by Razor before they are sent to the client and Razor doesn't know about the JavaScript code, it only knows C#. All JavaScript code runs on the browser.

I suggest you use the POST method to send your comments.
You can use this code to send them:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", new { parametar = 0 }, new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "beforeThis",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    Url = Url.Action("AddComment")
}))
{
    @Html.TextArea("Contents")
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="postavi btn btn-primary" />
}
```